# Asp.net on visual studio .net 2003 web component Issues

Tags: asp.net, iis, frameworks, .net-1.1

I want to run ASP.NET on VS 2003 but it raises an error which says:

> "Visual studio has detected that web server is running asp.net version
>   1.0.The web application you are creating or opening can be configured to be compliant with asp.net 1.0. However, the web application will
>   not be able to use the new features from asp.net 1.1."

When I choose the option "*Make the application compliant with asp.net 1.0*", then it is unable to set the compliance saying

> "Visual Studio.NET cannot create or open the application. The
>   likeliest problem is that required components are not installed on the
>   local web server. Run Visual Studio.NET setup and add the web
>   development component."

Answer (score 8):

It seems that you are running **Visual Studio 2003 on Vista**, which is not supported.

1. **By default, Vista does not include .NET Framework 1.1 SP1**. Install it first. Make sure that SP1 is installed. If you look into properties of "*c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322\mscorsvr.dll*", you should get the version 1.1.4322.2032.
2. **Enable IIS 6 Compatibility** in Control Panel -> Program and Features -> Turn Windows features on or off. Check "*IIS 6 Management Compatibility*" under "*Internet Information Servces*".
3. **Register .NET 1.1 with IIS** by running "*c:\Windows\MIcrosoft.net\Framework\v1.1.4322\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir*". It will create the Application Pool targeted to Framework 1.1 with Classic pipeline in IIS7 and set Enable32BitAppOnWin64 property to true on 64bit OS.
4. **Allow ASP.NET 1.1 in IIS7.** Open the IIS Manager and click on the computer name in left tree. In main window select "*ISAPI and CGI Restrictions*" and make sure that ASP.NET v1.1.4322 is enabled. If not, select it and click Allow link on right side.
5. When you create an application on any directory that runs .NET 1.1 or lower, always **select Application Pool that is targeted to Framework 1.1**. For already configured applications, you have to change it manually.

Comment: suddenly none of my 1.1 sites would open on windows 7 and I was getting this error - odd because last week they worked just fine... Anyway - great step by step detailed instructions and I'm up and working again.  Thanks!

Comment: Already did step 1 to 5, and i'm still getting this error! any other idea?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to update the script map of the ASP.NET application within IIS to use the *newer* version of the framework. I assume that .NET 1.1 framework and VS 2003 are already installed without issues.

Here is an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kdfe21k(VS.71).aspx) that should explain how to register the ASP.NET application within IIS to use the .NET 1.1 version using the aspnet_regiis.exe tool. Command-line reference for the tool is available [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h(vs.71).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

> Visual Studio.NET cannot create or open the application. The likeliest problem is that required components are not installed on the local web server. Run Visual Studio.NET setup and add the web development component.

I faced this problem when I copied the project folder from the network shared location to my local system.

Solution: Create a empty folder in your local system. Copy the files from the original folder into the newly created empty folder.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the accepted answer, you may also need to add the actual "Web Development" component that is included with the Visual Studio 2003 setup file.

While in the menu, even after you install ASP.NET v1.1 & associated Hotfixes/security updates, as well as FrontPage Extensions for your version of IIS, you may STILL see a red X over the installation component.

This may seem very hacky, but for some reason the installer doesn't seem to do a very thorough check - just click the "Red X" and the "Update Now!" icon becomes visible, then you can install the component just fine.

**Specs:** Windows 10, Visual Studio .NET 2003 Enterprise

**TIP**: If you are running a newer version of IIS, you won't be able to "just create" an ASP.NET 1.1 application pool. You'll need to enter these appcmd.exe commands:

```
appcmd create apppool /name:"YOURPOOLNAME"
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:"YOURPOOLNAME" /enable32BitAppOnWin64:true
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:"YOURPOOLNAME" /managedRuntimeVersion:"v1.1"
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:"YOURPOOLNAME" /managedPipelineMode:"Classic"
appcmd set apppool /apppool.name:"YOURPOOLNAME" /autoStart:true
```