# how to solve this issue "Visual studio .Net cannot create or open the application VS2003"?

Tags: iis-7.5, visual-studio-2003

I tried to open my old projects developed by VS2003 but I am not able to open in Visual studio 2003. 
Whenever I tried to create a new project or open my existing project in VS 2003 it will populate a error dialogue box .

Its Showing error like "**Visual studio .Net cannot create or open the application. The likeliest problem is that required components are not installed on the local web server. Run visual studio .net setup and add the web development component**"

I noticed one thing that when I tried to create a new project It will automatically point to the location

```
     http://localhost/newproject
```

I dont know why it is?

For opening existing project in my application Do I need to configure my application into IIS or in inetpub->wwwwroot folder? If so How can I configure my application into IIS? Please tell me the steps.

Anybody Please help me on this I have to solve this by today! Thanks !

Comment: At the least, you probably need to install the IIS 6 backward compatibility features into IIS. But you should also be aware the VS2003 is leaving even [*extended* support](http://support.microsoft.com/lifecycle/search/?sort=PN&alpha=Visual+Studio) in October this year - you should really be looking into upgrading the projects using a more up to date version of the product (considering VS2013 is due to be CTPed soon, you're soon going to be **5** versions behind)

Comment: Yes . I need to upgrade my projects into 2010 version, before that I should know about existing project then only I can upgrade my old projects into new version of projects. For understanding about existing project and its code I need to open it in VS2003. Please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

open inetmgr (start - on search program and files type "inetmgr"
expand your server - sites - default web site - right click - add application
Enter Alias at your case : newproject 
Application pool select ASP.NET 1.1 (must install first)
Physical path, choose your web folder.

turn off skype or Change skype port.
another suggestions, look CZFox's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/661165/asp-net-on-visual-studio-net-2003-web-component-issues)